# What are convergent sequences in a given metric space?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let on $ \mathbb{R} $ be given a metric  $d$, $$d(x, y) =\begin{cases} |x-y| +1& x > 0 \text{ or(exclusive or) } y>0 \\
|x-y|& \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} $$
What are convergent sequences in that space? I think that the only problem is with sequences that converge towards 0. They do not converge here? Because $\epsilon - 1 $ does not have to be positive?

Comment: I just fixed that expression to look better. For future reference: (1) \abs is not a code. Just use vertical bars |. (2) If you want text inside a construct like the cases environment, use \text{ } to enclose it, so it doesn't go into the math font and have its spaces stripped. (3) The cases environment, like other array environments, supports separating the values and conditions with the & delimiter. With that, no need for the word "if".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sequence will converge to $0$ iff it converges to $0$ *from the left*, i.e. if it converges to $0$ in the standard metric and contains finitely many positive members.